# How to always display the plus icon in my search box

Tags: jquery, html, css, search

I have a sample code that is displaying a search box that has some animation with css and uses jquery to toggle it.

Within my code I have an extra span element with a plus icon to the right. How can I keep the plus icon (only) always remain visible when the search is expanded and when it is contracted?

```js
$("p").hide();
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.search').toggleClass('inactive').find('input').focus();
  $(this).parent('.search').siblings('div.title').toggleClass('hideTitle')
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);*/
}

.input-group:active,
.input-group:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
}

.input-group.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.input-group .input-group-addon i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}

.input-group input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}

.inactive {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.hideTitle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Search Inputs</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="title titleDiv">Title</div>
    <div class="input-group search inactive pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        <span class="input-group-addon add"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just position it in a way that it is alway visible..it is no hidden in anyway in your code so i think it is just out of view

Comment: @guradio I do want to keep it within the input-group-addon though, since the styling is in the input-group and input-group-addon classes in bootstrap 4

Comment: Which element has the plus icon? There doesn't appear to be anything in your above code that would be creating a plus.

Comment: @guradio  <span class="input-group-addon add"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span> Its hidden initially.

Answer (score 0):

How about do it with css?

```
.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  **opacity: 1;**
}
```

```js
$("p").hide();
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.search').toggleClass('inactive').find('input').focus();
  $(this).parent('.search').siblings('div.title').toggleClass('hideTitle')
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*border-radius: 2px;*/
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);*/
}

.input-group:active,
.input-group:hover {
  /*background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);*/
}

.input-group.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.input-group .input-group-addon {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

.input-group .input-group-addon i {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  align-self: center;
  color: #777;
}

.input-group input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
}

.inactive {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.inactive .input-group-addon:not(:first-child) {
  **opacity: 1;**
}

.row {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.hideTitle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>Search Inputs</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="title titleDiv">Title</div>
    <div class="input-group search inactive pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>
   </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

      <span class="input-group-addon opener">
    <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        <span class="input-group-addon add"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>
      </span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only want the plus icon to be visible at all times, the behavior of the search and close icon should remain how they are intended to be displayed.